# Compare within a group python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

df_test = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [912665, 455378, 938724, 557830
                         ],
                    "Company Name": ["112 ","112 ","SSS","SSS"
                            ],

                   "Date": ['2018-09-02 00:00:00','2019-02-27 00:00:00','2019-05-05 00:00:00','2018-03-21 00:00:00' 
                        ],
                    "Type": ['Type1','Type2','Type1','Type2' 
                        ],
                   "ngroup": [0, 0,1,1]}

                      )

df_test
```

I need to do a comparison within each 'ngroup' 0,1... by date (or any other column if I need to).

For this example, I have group 0 and 1 called ngroup. Within each group I have only two rows for every group. 
And Company Type called Type like Type 1 and Type 2
I need to check if Date for Type 1 is greater that for Type 2. If it is, then I need to say that for example "Type 1 joined first" and if it is not, then Type 2 joined first.

I would also like to add it to my initial dataframe after that as a new column status.

UPD:
So my expected result would be liks this

```
df_test_expected_result = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [912665, 455378, 938724, 557830
                         ],
                    "Company Name": ["112 ","112 ","SSS","SSS"
                            ],

                   "Date": ['2018-09-02 00:00:00','2019-02-27 00:00:00','2019-05-05 00:00:00','2018-03-21 00:00:00' 
                        ],
                    "Type": ['Type1','Type2','Type1','Type2' 
                        ],
                   "ngroup": [0, 0,1,1],
                    "expected_result": ["Type 1 joined first","Type 1 joined first","Type 2 joined first","Type 2 joined first" ]
                                       }

                      )
df_test_expected_result
```

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Done. I have just added update in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, we need a comparison boolean to test against each group.

```
bool_comp = df_test.groupby(['ngroup'])['Date'].transform('min')

df_test["res"] = np.where(
    df_test["Date"] <= bool_comp,
    df_test["Type"] + " Joined First",
    df_test["Type"] + " Joined Later",
)

print(df_test)

       ID Company Name       Date   Type  ngroup                 res
0  912665         112  2018-09-02  Type1       0  Type1 Joined First
1  455378         112  2019-02-27  Type2       0  Type2 Joined Later
2  938724          SSS 2019-05-05  Type1       1  Type1 Joined Later
3  557830          SSS 2018-03-21  Type2       1  Type2 Joined First
```

Edit, just saw your expected output, we can apply your first condition then forward and backfill by the group.

```
df_test["res"] = np.where(
    df_test["Date"] <= bool_comp,
    df_test["Type"] + " Joined First",
    np.nan
)

df_test["res"] = df_test["res"].fillna(df_test.groupby("ngroup")["res"].ffill().bfill())

       ID Company Name       Date   Type  ngroup                 res
0  912665         112  2018-09-02  Type1       0  Type1 Joined First
1  455378         112  2019-02-27  Type2       0  Type1 Joined First
2  938724          SSS 2019-05-05  Type1       1  Type2 Joined First
3  557830          SSS 2018-03-21  Type2       1  Type2 Joined First
```